# Autofac: adding a decorator to a delegate registration that takes parameters

Tags: autofac

I'm trying to manage registration of my WCF clients using autofac.

I need to resolve `Func<MachineEndpoint, IFooService>`, so I had registered the service using:

```
builder.Register((c, p) => FooService(c, p.TypedAs<MachineEndpoint>())).UseWcfSafeRelease()
```

Where FooService is:

```
private IJobService FooService(IComponentContext c, MachineEndpoint endpoint) {...}
```

This works fine, but I want to add a decorator to this to handle certain security errors, so I tried the following:

```
builder.Register((c, p) => FooService(c, p.TypedAs<MachineEndpoint>())).UseWcfSafeRelease().Named<IFooService>("simple foo service");
builder.RegisterDecorator<IFooService>((c, p, inner) => Wrap(inner, p.TypedAs<MachineEndpoint>(), c.Resolve<CertificateLookupCache>()), "simple foo service");
```

but I get a DependecyResolutionException:

```
Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while executing a resolve operation. See the InnerException for details. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at MyModule.<Load>b__4(IComponentContext c, IEnumerable`1 p) in MyModule.cs:line 30 (the first line above)
   at Autofac.Builder.RegistrationBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass1`1.<ForDelegate>b__0(IComponentContext c, IEnumerable`1 p)
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Delegate.DelegateActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Features.LightweightAdapters.LightweightAdapterRegistrationSource.<>c__DisplayClass3.<RegistrationsFor>b__1(IComponentContext c, IEnumerable`1 p)
   at Autofac.Builder.RegistrationBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass1`1.<ForDelegate>b__0(IComponentContext c, IEnumerable`1 p)
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Delegate.DelegateActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace:
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at lambda_method(Closure , MachineEndpoint )
```

How can I register these functions so that I can get the MachinEndpoint parameter passed to both the WCF client object and the decorator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by your parameter usage: `p.TypedAs<MachineEndpoint>()` because there is currently a limitation in Autofac namely that the `RegisterDecorator` does not pass through parameters when creating the `inner` decorated object.

So when it tries to create `inner` with the `(c, p) => FooService(c, p.TypedAs<MachineEndpoint>())` the `(IEnumerable<Parameter> p)` will be empty so you get the exception.

You can basically do two things:

You can try to reorganize your code in a way that it doesn't use `p.TypedAs<MachineEndpoint>()` anymore.

Or

Because your `IFooService` anyway a WCF service which does not have multiple implementations you can register your Decorator by "hand":

```cs
builder.Register((c, p) => FooService(c, p.TypedAs<MachineEndpoint>()))
       .UseWcfSafeRelease()
       .Named<IFooService>("simple foo service");
builder.Register<IFooService>((c, p) => 
     Wrap(c.ResolveNamed<IFooService>("simple foo service",
          TypedParameter.From(p.TypedAs<MachineEndpoint>())),
          p.TypedAs<MachineEndpoint>(),
          c.Resolve<CertificateLookupCache>()));
```